# Different application of Arden's theorem leads to different answers

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

So, I have to solve for the following set of equations

> $q_1$ = $q_1$a + $q_2$b + $\epsilon$
>
> $q_2$ = $q_1$a + $q_2$b + $q_3$a
>
> $q_3$ = $q_2$a

There are two ways to do this.

I did this

> $q_1$ = $q_2$b + $\epsilon$ + $q_1$a
>
> $q_1$ = ($q_2$b + $\epsilon$)a* Applying Arden's theorem

Now substituting in $q_2$ the values of $q_1$ and $q_3$

> $q_2$ = $q_2$ba*a + a*a + $q_2$b + $q_2$aa
>
> $q_2$ = a*a + $q_2$(ba*a+b+aa)
>
> $q_2$ = a*a(ba*a+b+aa)* Applying Arden's theorem
>
> $q_2$ = a*a(ba*+aa)*

Now substituting in $q_3$, the answer should be

> $q_3$ = a*a(ba*+aa)*a

However, the correct answer is

> (a + a(b+aa)*b)*a(b+aa)*a

which can be obtained by first substituting $q_3$ in $q_2$, and then substituting $q_2$ in $q_1$, and finally solving $q_2$, $q_3$ from the obtained regular expression for $q_1$.

Can someone tell where I have gone wrong in the above method, or am I applying ardens theorem in the wrong way ?

Comment: Every regular language can be described by infinitely many regular expressions.

Comment: You stumbled across something really interesting: The ordering in which you eliminate the q's can have a large effect on the size of the resulting regular expressions. See e.g. here for more background: https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.1656

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two regular expressions [describe the same language](https://bakkot.github.io/dfa-lib/regeq.html).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using various [Kleene algebraic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_algebra) properties, such as the following
$$
(u + v)^* = v^* (u v^*)^* = (v^* u)^* v^* = u^* (v u^*)^* = (u^* v)^* u^*,\\
u u^* = u^* u,\quad (u v)^* u = u (v u)^*,\quad
u^* φ(u)^* = u^*,\\
u + v = v + u,\quad
(u + v) w = u w + v w,\quad
u 1 = u,\quad
1 + u u^* = u^*,
$$
where $φ(u)$ denotes an arbitrary Kleene-algebraic polynomial in $u$, we can write
$$\begin{align}
a (a + b)^* a
&= a a^* (b a^*)^* a\\
&= a a^* (a a)^* (b a^* (a a)^*)^* a\\
&= a^* a (a a)^* (b a^* (a a)^*)^* a\\
&= a^* a (b a^* + a a)^* a,\\
\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}
a (a + b)^* a
&= a a^* (b a^*)^* a\\
&= a a^* (a a)^* (b a^* (a a)^*)^* a\\
&= a a^* (b a^* + a a)^* a\\
&= a a^* (b (1 + a a^*) + a a)^* a\\
&= a a^* (b + a a + b a a^*)^* a\\
&= a a^* ((b + a a)^* b a a^*)^* (b + a a)^* a\\
&= (a a^* (b + a a)^* b)^* a a^* (b + a a)^* a\\
&= (a^* a (b + a a)^* b)^* a^* a (b + a a)^* a\\
&= (a + a (b + a a)^* b)^* a (b + a a)^* a.
\end{align}$$

So, actually, you could have said it was $a (a + b)^* a$.